# NodeJS API Request - parsed JSON Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have this request which provides me JSON syntax

```
request( url, function (error, response) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(response.body))
```

This generates the following within the console:

```
{
  query: 'Manchester Holiday Inn',
  moresuggestions: 2,
  suggestions: [
    { group: 'CITY_GROUP', entities: [] },
    { group: 'HOTEL_GROUP', entities: [Array] },
    { group: 'LANDMARK_GROUP', entities: [] },
    { group: 'TRANSPORT_GROUP', entities: [Array] }
  ]
}
```

within the HOTEL GROUP syntax there is some additional information:

```
{
   "query":"Manchester Holiday Inn",
   "moresuggestions":0,
   "suggestions":[
      {},
      {
         "group":"HOTEL_GROUP",
         "entities":[
            {
               "geoId":"16071381",
               "destinationId":"4234234",
               "type":"HOTEL",
               "caption":"Manchester Holiday Inn Hotel",
               "name":"Manchester Holiday Inn Hotel"
            }
         ]
      },
```

I want to extract the destination ID and Hotel Name

```
     request( url, function (error, response) {
          const data = JSON.parse(response.body)
          hotelName = data['suggestions[1].entities[0].name'],
          hotelID = data["suggestions[1].entities[0].destinationId"]
          
          console.log(hotelName)
          console.log(hotelID)
```

But the output from the console shows that hotelName and hotelID are undefined. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
          undefined
          undefined
```

Comment: Please follow this `hotelName = data.suggestions[1].entities[0].name`

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you're using to access the properties is wrong – you'll need

```
const hotelName = data.suggestions[1].entities[0].name
const hotelID = data.suggestions[1].entities[0].destinationId
```

instead.

You can also use object destructuring, like so:

```
const {name: hotelName, destinationId: hotelID} = data.suggestions[1].entities[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access to it like this

```
data["suggestions"][1]["entities"][0][name]
```